# Counting the occurrence of each Chinese character within a text file

Tags: python, text, character

I am trying to learn Chinese the fast way. One great tool is to learn every character before I read the text where it appears.

I would like a function that reads a text file, identifies each Chinese character (or hanzi) and classes them by number of occurrences.

I am a total noob when it comes to programming but I am ready to give it a go in Python or any other language I can learn fast.

For example, input：

```
我妹妹现在在北京
```

Output:

```
在 - 2
妹 - 2
我 - 1
现 - 1
北 - 1
京 - 1
```

As a reminder, there are over 40,000 hanzi even though 5,000 are more than enough in daily use.

Answer (score 4):

Using python3:

```
from collections import Counter

print(Counter(open("test.txt").read()))
Counter({'妹': 2, '在': 2, '现': 1, '京': 1, '我': 1, ' ': 1, '北': 1}
```

With python 2 use `io.open`:

```
from io import open
print(Counter(open("test.txt").read()))
Counter({u'\u5728': 2, u'\u59b9': 2, u' ': 1, u'\u4eac': 1, u'\u6211': 1, u'\u73b0': 1, u'\u5317': 1})
```

Comment: This seems to work only with the few characters that you have specified. As I said, I don't want to manually input 5,000 characters in my code, let alone 50,000

Comment: I did not specify any characters, I used the characters in your question, if it does not work for you then you have encoding issues which *This seems to work only with the few characters that you have specified* gives absolutely no insight into